# Procedures between a system of neighborhoods and a topology.

Tags: general-topology

I'm doing this exercise.

[image]

I'm not sure what I need to prove here. Are the procedures maps, or are they something else?

Comment: If I give you a topology (without any known properties), how would you construct a neighborhood? Then try to formalize your thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a topology, for each $x$ in X, define the nhoods of $x$ to be all the sets $A$ for which exists an open set $U$ with $x \in U$, $U \subset A$.

Given a system of nhoods, define an open nhood $U$ of $x$ to be a nhood of $x$ that is the union of all the nhoods $V$ of $a$ for every $a \in U$ with $V \subset U$.
To show that those open nhoods are a topology one uses if $x$ in $U$ $\cap$ V then exists nhood W of $x$ with $W \subset U \cap V$.

Nhood spaces are more of historical interest than useful.